# .bashrc save for export

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed anaconda but haven't added to bashrc.

In terminal I type:

```
export PATH="/home/my_pc/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

and then `python` all works well.

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

But as I close terminal everything returns to the old configuration:

```
my_pc@y_pc:~$ conda
conda: command not found
my_pc@my_pc:~$ python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 19 2017, 14:48:08) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170118] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

How could I save the new export PATH configuration?

Answer (score 3):

This should do it for you:

```
# Permanent change that requires logging out
echo 'export PATH="/home/my_pc/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or, if you wish:

```
# ~/.bashrc is sourced every time you launch a new terminal, so no need for logging out
echo 'export PATH="/home/my_pc/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Does it have to display anything? I put first echo command but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: No, you should not see anything on the screen. The first solution requires that you log out and log back in and (important) assumes that your `~/.bash_profile` is read when you log in. If it does not work, use the second solution - it will work when you start a new Bash session.

Answer (score 2):

You should add this to your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` file:

```
export PATH="/home/my_pc/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```